# What exactly is っていう defining here?

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

I'm having a little trouble translating the following passage ---

> なのにあんたときたら三年前再会してからは何かっていうと電話してきて…新商品のパンが美味しいとか、どぉっでもいいのよ！

I've read various guides about っていう and how it's used but it all seems to have flown out the window when I read the above in a novel.

My translation of it (please do correct me if I happen to be wrong):

なのに - is a conjunction so but/however etc;

あんたときたら - "concerning you/as for you" (I thinkときたら is interchangeable with the は particle?)

三年前再会してから - "after we met again 3 years ago"

何か - something/anything

っていう - called/meaning (confused about what it's defining or describing here)

電話してきて - "phoned me"

新商品のパンが美味しいとか - "new stock of bread is delicious amongst other things"

どぉっでもいい - it looks to be どうでもいい which means "it doesn't matter"

You see, I find it difficult to actually put all of that into a sentence because the っていう is really throwing me off, what is its purpose in this particular sentence? any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://jisho.org/word/何かと言うと

Answer (score 4):

The major problem with your part-by-part translation are these parts:

> 何か - something/anything
>
> っていう - called/meaning

Neither would work unfortunately.  The phrase that you should instead be looking at is:

> 「何{なに}かっていうと」,

which is a colloquial way of saying 「何かというと」, which means:

> "**using every possible pretext to ~~**"

So, that part of the sentence means:

> "you've been using every possible pretext to call me and ~~~"

Finally, for the pronunciation-conscious learners:

「なにか」 meaning "something" and 「なにか」 in this expression are ***pronounced differently***.

「[なにか]{HLL}」 for "something"

「[なにか]{LHH}」 in the expression in question